# Count reactions on message and perform action after there is a certain amount of reactions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like my bot to take away someone's role after certain amount of reactions is reached on vote message. Any idea how to check how many of them are currently added on the message?

```
@client.command()
async def derank(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    counter = 0
    votes_to_pass = 2
    msg = await ctx.send("Member: " + discord.Member + "\n Reason: " + reason)
    # count reactions on msg
    if counter >= votes_to_pass:
        await ctx.send("User deranked")
        # take the role away from user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@client.command()
async def derank(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    votes_to_pass = 2
    msg = await ctx.send(f"Member: {member}\nReason: {reason}") # This line was erroneous, fixed it. Try to use f-strings quite more than concatinating.
    # count reactions on msg
    try:
        async def reactionFunction():
            while True:
                reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check = lambda reaction, user: str(reaction.emoji) == '', timeout=60.0) # Wait 1 minute for any reaction
                if reaction.message.id == msg.id: # If the message reacted to is the one we sent (msg)
                    for reaction in reaction.message.reactions:
                        if (reaction.count >= votes_to_pass): # If the reactions of that message are the number we game (votes_to_pass) or more then
                            return # This returns out of the function.
                            # As you can see, the reason I used a function is so I can be able to return
                            # This is because using break will just break out of the for look but not the while loop but return breaks out of the whole thing as it's a function.
                            # If only python made it easy to break twice, but anyway this works
        await reactionFunction()


        # This is the part where it removes the role.
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='ROLE_NAME') # Get a role by name. To get it by ID replace name ='ROLE_NAME' to name = ID
        await member.remove_roles(role) # Remove the role that we got (role) from the member mentioned.

        await ctx.send("User deranked") # Say this after removing the roles
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Role is never removed.

Comment: Works fine. I had to change one line.
`if len(reaction.message.reactions) >= votes_to_pass:`
I also added:
`role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="placeholder")
await member.remove_roles(role)`
under `await ctx.send("User deranked")` line

Comment: Any idea how could I count only thumbs up  emoji?

Comment: Add a check; change the line that says `reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0)` to something like this `reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check = lambda reaction, user: str(reaction.emoji) == '', timeout=60.0)`
This will make it check if the reaction is a thumbs up emoji and only continue if it is a thumbs but if it's not then it'll continue waiting till the timer finishes or till the emoji as a thumbs up and the votes have been reached

Comment: Unfortunately now the counter isn't working at all and the vote is always timing out.

Comment: Shadows name 'reaction' from outer scope. Same with user

Comment: `message.reactions` only counts how many different reactions exist on a message. But it seems like what you want is to count how many clicks on the same reaction (emoji) (in this case the thumbs up emoji). In this case you'll have to use `discord.Reaction.count` I've edited the whole reply now.

Comment: Also, if you want it to wait longer, change the 60.0 (1 minute in seconds) on line 9 to any seconds longer than 60 so it can wait longer